# Generate compiler error if property is not set

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I want to be able to create a compiler error/warning if a certain property in my object is not set.  Let's say I have the following class:

```
interface

type
  TBarkevent = procedure (Bark : String) of object;

  TDog = class
  private
    FOnBark : TBarkevent;
    procedure SetBark(const Value: TBarkevent);
    function GetBark: TBarkEvent;
  public
    procedure Bark;
    property OnBark : TBarkEvent read GetBark write SetBark;
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation

{ TDog }

procedure TDog.Bark;
begin
  if Assigned(OnBark) then
    OnBark('Woof!')
end;

constructor TDog.Create;
begin
end;

function TDog.GetBark: TBarkEvent;
begin
  Result := FOnBark;
end;

procedure TDog.SetBark(const Value: TBarkevent);
begin
  FOnBark := Value;
end;
```

I make use of the `TDog` class in another unit like this:

```
var
  Dog : TDog;
begin
  Dog := TDog.Create;
  Dog.OnBark := DogBark;
  Dog.Bark;
```

Now, once the `Bark()` procedure is called, the `OnBark` event is triggered.

My Question:

Is it possible for me to make it *mandatory* to specify the `OnBark` property, so that a compiler error/warning is emitted if the event is not set?

Comment: Sometimes you have to step up to the plate and get things right. The compiler can't do your job for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The problem is, years from now someone other than me could end up using this code and having something that tells them that  they have made a mistake early on could save alot of time and effort

Comment: That's called documentation

Comment: Indeed, `Dog.ScratchEar;` isn't going to do any magic for you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your class as:

```
TDog = class
private
  FOnBark : TBarkevent;
  procedure SetBark(const Value: TBarkevent);
  function GetBark: TBarkEvent;
public
  procedure Bark;
  property OnBark : TBarkEvent read GetBark write SetBark;
  constructor Create(Bark : TBarkEvent);
end;
```

That way, you can't instantiate a `TDog` object without specifying an event. If you try, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: True, however the event could still be assigned a `nil` value, which does not satisfy the OP's requirement.

Comment: Agreed with @RemyLebeau, but its possible to check for nil inside the constructor and raise and exception in that case

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Why not? Assigning a NIL value is still assigning a value. There's even a check in the Bark method as to whether or not the value is non-NIL, so it is obvious (to me) that a NIL value is a valid value. If not, the Bark method should just call the FOnBark event and let it crash if it isn't assigned a non-NIL value. If NIL is not a valid value, a check in the CONSTRUCTOR should be implemented, and the check in the Bark method should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **No.** It is not possible to check this on compile-time for a property like this.

To make it ***almost* mandatory** to implement a `OnBark` event, you could add it as a constructor parameter, instead of publishing it as a read/write-property. Then, you could use `Assert()` to check it at run-time, when calling the constructor whether a valid callback method has been passed to the constructor.

To make it ***really* mandatory**, you could declare the following:

```
TCustomDog = class
public
  procedure Bark; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

Thus, everybody using `TCustomDog` class has to implement `Bark` procedure. If he does not, a compiler warning will be emitted.

Comment: Just to clarify: The CONSTRUCTOR way would generate an error. The ABSTRACT way would (by default) only generate a warning... Thus (IMO) the CONSTRUCTOR way would be the better choice.

Comment: @kobik: it doesn't.  The code would have to derive another class from `TCustomDog` and override `Bark()` with a concrete implementation instead of using an event.

Comment: @HeartWare That's correct. I myself would go for the constructor way, too.